# Деструктор в  java

Tags: java

Как в классе описать деструктор и как его потом вызвать?

Comment: То есть гугл, википедия и мануалы по первой ссылке в поисковой выдаче - это все не для нас.

Comment: я думаю, человек до последнего надеялся, что там они все таки есть. Я считаю, что если бы в Java добавили специально расширение, такой себе "необязательный наглый деструктор", который можно вставлять по надобности, то это сильно бы улучшило производительность и качество работы. Но только, если код пишет хороший специалист. А для рядовых это будет вредительством.

Comment: > Но только, если код пишет хороший специалист.

я думаю что хороший специалист уже давно привык к особенностям языка и не заморачивается вопросами которыми часто задаются начинающие: "а почему... <нет деструктора в java>"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В java нет деструкторов в прямом понимании этого слова. Но есть finalize (почитать -  [офф дока](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()), [finalize и Finalizer](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144544/) и [Метод finalize](http://www.linkex.ru/java/finalize.php) ).

Но он может вызываться в произвольные моменты.

Если же деструктор нужен, тогда нужно просто создать метод с правильным названием (closeFile, freeResourse, и тому подобное) и вызывать по надобности.

Если же нужны деструкторы как в с++, тогда нужно выбрать правильный язык:).

Answer (score 8):

В java нет деструкторов потому, что нет delete. Удаление объекта происходит неявно, когда сборщик мусора обнаружит, что на него не осталось ссылок. Тогда он вызовет у него finalize(), но когда именно это произойдет и произойдет ли вообще, система не гарантирует. Поэтому этот метод не используют, а объекту добавляют явный метод, освобождающий его ресурсы. Лучше назвать это метод close(), а класс объекта пусть имплементирует [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), тогда в некоторых обстоятельствах close() будет вызываться автоматически.