# Как создать/вызывать деструктор в Java классе?

Tags: java, ооп

Здравствуйте. Недавно изучаю Java и возник вопрос при создании класса. А конкретно - мне нужно написать деструктор. Да, я понимаю, что такого формально нет в Java, но всё же. Кое где видел совет использовать finalize, но это не лучшее решение.
Итак, суть в том, что есть у меня класс, который должен слушать сообщения от сервера и выкидывать эти сообщения в JTextArea. Происходить это должно пока есть соединение или пока не нажму на кнопку "выключить". Соответственно тогда хочу удалить экземпляр этого класса и всё забыть. Вопрос: "Как насильно сделать деструктор в собственном классе"

Заранее спасибо. Очень нужна помощь

Comment: Когда удалены все ссылки на объект, то у него после этого один путь - в топку GC

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/249242/16781

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону интерфейсов Closeable/AutoCloseable, это канонический путь в Java получить то, что вы хотите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JTextArea` занимает не значительную область памяти, что думаю создание деструктора не столь необходимо. В Java за нас все это делает сборщик мусора (garbage collector). Он время от времени проверяет не используемые объекты и удаляет их.

К примеру если после использования `JTextArea` вы все-таки хотите ее удалить, то вам надо всего лишь задать значение `null` к переменному `textArea` типа `JTextArea`. После этого сборщик мусора (garbage collector) обнаружит, что на `textArea` никакой объект не ссылается и сразу удаляет из памяти. Он это делает настолько эффективно и быстро (за доля секунды), что это не отразится на производительность вашего приложения.

Comment: Понял, спасибо больше